# Mongodb aggregation - first create item list and get intersect of items with rating details

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230449/mongodb-aggregation-first-create-item-list-and-get-intersect-of-items/31230680#31230680)   before. The question

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5539d45ee3cd0e48e99c3fa6"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "movieId" : 6,
    "rating" : 2.0000000000000000,
    "timestamp" : 9.80731e+008
}

    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5539d45ee3cd0e48e99c1fa7"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "movieId" : 22,
    "rating" : 3.0000000000000000,
    "timestamp" : 9.80731e+008
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5539d45ee3cd0e48e99c1fa8"),
    "userId" : 1,
    "movieId" : 32,
    "rating" : 2.0000000000000000,
    "timestamp" : 9.80732e+008
},


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5539d45ee3cd0e48e99c1fa9"),
    "userId" : 2,
    "movieId" : 32,
    "rating" : 4.0000000000000000,
    "timestamp" : 9.80732e+008
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5539d45ee3cd0e48e99c1fa3"),
    "userId" : 2,
    "movieId" : 6,
    "rating" : 5.0000000000000000,
    "timestamp" : 9.80731e+008
}
```

Then needed to get the common(intersect) items for given two users (like userId:1 and userId:2) like [6,32].

But now i need to get that with ratings of each of them like **[ {"movieId":6,"user1_rating" : 2,"user2_rating" : 4},{"movieId":32,"user1_rating" : 2,"user2_rating" : 5} ]**

How can i get that?
I tried to do with

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"$or":[{"userId":2},{"userId":1}]}},
  {$group: {_id: "$movieId", users: {$push: {"userId":"$userId","rating":"$rating"}}}},
  {$project: { movieId: "$_id", _id: 0,rating:"$users.rating", allUsersIncluded: { $setIsSubset: [ [1,2], "$users.userId"]}}},
  {$match: { allUsersIncluded: true }},
  {$group: { _id: null, movies: {$push: {"movie":"$movieId","Rating":"$rating"}}}}
])
```

But I get [ {"movie":6,0 : 2,1 : 4},{"movie":32,0 : 2,1 : 5} ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i achieved my target.The answer is

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"$or":[{"userId":2},{"userId":1}]}},
  {$group: {_id: "$movieId", users: {$addToSet: {"userId":"$userId","rating":"$rating"}}}},
  {$project: { movieId: "$_id", _id: 0,user:"$users", allUsersIncluded: { $setIsSubset: [ [1,2], "$users.userId"]}}},
  {$match: { allUsersIncluded: true }},
  {$group: { _id: null, movies: {$addToSet: {"movie":"$movieId","user":"$user"}}}}
])
```